# How to create program dependence graph in java

Tags: java

I am trying to generate slice of the program in java and need a way to generate program dependence graph of the program in java, please help me to generate program dependence graph. I have tried JFlex I dont know it is right or not,but it did generate DFA and NDFA. but I dont understand how it works, if you ever used it please comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven try dependency plugin: `mvn depedency:tree`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IVY with ANT, you can simply put in the build.xml this line

```
<ivy:report graph="false">
```

It will generate an html file with the summary of the dependencies.

If you want remove graph="false" of course ;)

here the documentation
http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/use/report.html